# How do I track the Unity position of physical objects the player is interacting with using Hololens2 hand tracking data?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, virtual-reality, hololens, mrtk

Basically I am working on a mixed reality experience using the Hololens2 and Unity, where the player has several physical objects they need to interact with, as well as virtual objects. One of the physical objects is a gun controller that has an IMU to detect acceleration and orientation. My main challenge is this : how do I get the physical object's position in Unity, in order to accurately fire virtual projectiles at a virtual enemy?

My current idea is to have the player position the physical weapon inside a virtual bounding box at the start of the game. I can then track the position of the virtual box through collision with the player's hands when they pick up the physical controller. Does OnCollisionEnter, or a similar method, work with the Players hands? (see attached image)

[image: Gun Bounding Box]

I am also looking into the use of spatial awareness / image recognition / pose estimation to accomplish this task, as well as researching the use of a tracking base station to determine object position (similar to HTC Vive / Oculus Rift ).

Any suggestions, resources, and assistance is greatly appreciated here. Thank you!

EDIT UPDATE 11/30/2020 :
Hernando commented below suggesting QR codes, assume for this project we are not allowed to use QR codes, and we want as as precise orientation data as possible. Thanks Hernando!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For locating the object, QR code would definitely be the recommendation to find quickly with HL2 device.  I have seen the QR approach in multiple venues too for VR LBE experiences like being described here.  QR code is just sitting on top the device.

Otherwise, if the controller in question supports Bluetooth, can possibly pair the device and if device has location information, can possible transmit the location of where it is at.  Based on what I am seeing from all of the above, this would be a custom solution and highly dependent on the controller abilities to be seen if QR codes are out of the equation.  I have witnessed some controller solutions to first start the user experience to do something like touch the floor to get an initial reference point.  Or alternatively doing something like always picking up the gun from specific location in the real world like some local based experiences do before starting.

Good luck with project, just my advice from using systems with VR

Answer (score 0):

Is the controller allowed to paste multiple QRcodes? If allowed, we recommend you use [QRCode tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/qr-code-tracking) to assist in locating your controller. If you prefer to use image recognition, object detection, or other technologies, it needs Azure service or some third-party library, more information please see:[Computer Vision documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but unfortunately for this project we are specifically trying to do it without QR codes. How would you do it without QR codes?